# SQL generate rows for each date between records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a SQL query that returns records for employees status so I can later group by hour. My query will run for a specific day.

Sample of the data as follows

```
recID | EmployeeID |  StatusDate          |   Status  
100   |  1000      | 2015-01-20 09:01 AM  | logged-in
101   |  1000      | 2015-01-20 09:07 AM  | Break
102   |  2000      | 2015-01-20 09:08 AM  | logged-in
103   |  1000      | 2015-01-20 09:09 AM  | logged-in
104   |  1000      | 2015-01-20 09:11 AM  | Logged-Off
105   |  2000      | 2015-01-20 09:12 AM  | Logged-Off
```

What I am trying to get is a list of records per minute to account for the employee status. Result would be as follows

```
EmployeeID |  StatusDate          |   Status  
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:01 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:02 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:03 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:04 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:05 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:06 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:07 AM  | Break
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:08 AM  | Break
 2000      | 2015-01-20 09:08 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:09 AM  | logged-in
 2000      | 2015-01-20 09:09 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:10 AM  | logged-in
 2000      | 2015-01-20 09:10 AM  | logged-in
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:11 AM  | Logged-Off
 2000      | 2015-01-20 09:11 AM  | logged-in
 2000      | 2015-01-20 09:12 AM  | Logged-Off
 1000      | 2015-01-20 09:12 AM  | Logged-Off
```

Ultimate result would provide a count on how many users(employees) that carried the status per minute, so the result would be as follows:

```
DateTime             | Status      | Count
2015-01-20 09:01 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:02 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:03 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:04 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:05 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:06 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:07 AM  | Break       | 1
2015-01-20 09:08 AM  | Break       | 1
2015-01-20 09:08 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:09 AM  | logged-in   | 2
2015-01-20 09:10 AM  | logged-in   | 2
2015-01-20 09:11 AM  | Logged-Off  | 1
2015-01-20 09:11 AM  | logged-in   | 1
2015-01-20 09:12 AM  | Logged-Off  | 2
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little hard in 2008, but here it is:

```
DECLARE @Fact TABLE
    (
      EmpID INT ,
      dt DATETIME ,
      St NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO @Fact
VALUES  ( 1000, '2015-01-20 09:01', 'logged-in' ),
        ( 1000, '2015-01-20 09:07', 'Break' ),
        ( 2000, '2015-01-20 09:08', 'logged-in' ),
        ( 1000, '2015-01-20 09:09', 'logged-in' ),
        ( 1000, '2015-01-20 09:11', 'Logged-Off' ),
        ( 2000, '2015-01-20 09:12', 'Logged-Off' )


DECLARE @dates TABLE ( dt DATETIME )
DECLARE @count INT , @minDT DATETIME , @maxDT DATETIME


SELECT  @minDT = MIN(dt), @maxDT = MAX(dt) FROM @Fact

WHILE @minDT <= @maxDT
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO @dates
        VALUES  ( @minDT )
        SET @minDT = DATEADD(mi, 1, @minDT)
    END;

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   c.EmpID, d.dt, a.St
               FROM     @dates d
                        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT EmpID FROM   @Fact ) c
                        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    St
                                      FROM      @Fact f
                                      WHERE     f.EmpID = c.EmpID
                                                AND dt = ( SELECT MAX(dt)
                                                           FROM @Fact fi
                                                           WHERE fi.EmpID = c.EmpID AND fi.dt <= d.dt )
                                    ) a
             )
    SELECT  dt, St, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY dt, St
    ORDER BY dt, St DESC
```

Output:

```
dt                      St          Count
2015-01-20 09:01:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:02:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:03:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:04:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:05:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:06:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:07:00.000 Break   1
2015-01-20 09:08:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:08:00.000 Break   1
2015-01-20 09:09:00.000 logged-in   2
2015-01-20 09:10:00.000 logged-in   2
2015-01-20 09:11:00.000 Logged-Off  1
2015-01-20 09:11:00.000 logged-in   1
2015-01-20 09:12:00.000 Logged-Off  2
```

Comment: This is amazing!! I have been trying for two days using different methods and this one really stands out. With minor change in changing what gets added to the @fact table to use my real data. bingo. I was trying as much as possible not handle this within my application and your solution did it.

Comment: A tally or numbers table would be more efficient here than looping.

Comment: Sean, I am working on using your method to utilize a tally table, since it seems to be more efficient. Giorgi's response actually gave me the idea on how to get the initial result, but a tally table would be the way to go. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried ?

This looks like a simple:

```
Select DateTime, Status, Count(*)
...
Group by DateTime, Status
```

??

Comment: This won't return the "missing dates" 2015-01-20 09:02 AM to 2015-01-20 09:06 AM etc. You'll need a date table to (outer) join against for that. Try [Why You Simply Must Have a Date Table (Video)](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/simply-must-date-table-video/) or [Using common table expressions (CTE) to generate sequences](https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/)

Comment: ahh, if you need to "create rows", yes, you'll need either a date table, or a query to "make up rows", such as in Oracle:  select sysdate-level from dual connect by level <=1000;     ... but yeah, might need something like that.